# What's the correct way to get around the multi-inheritance restriction?

Tags: java, android, oop, multiple-inheritance, extends

I feel like every time I ask questions like these, people always ask for code, but then I post the code and no one ever responds again because I guess the code is too long. So I will try to be brief this time.

Consider an adapter class that extends this class, which provides functionality for expanding RecyclerViews:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter<MyParentViewHolder, MyChildViewHolder> ...
```

However I normally have another, separate adapter class (that I tried making myself) that provides functionality for adding checkboxes to RecyclerView items / providing multiselection. Example usage:

```
public class MyOtherAdapter extends CheckableAdapter<SomeType, SomeViewHolder> ...
```

that class happens to be short enough to post, just in case it's relelvant:

```
public abstract class CheckableAdapter<T extends CheckableObject, VH extends CheckableViewHolder> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VH> {
    private List<T> list;
    private boolean checkMode;

    public CheckableAdapter(List<T> list) {
        this.list = list;
        this.checkMode = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(VH holder, int position) {
        final CheckableObject checkableObject = list.get(position);
        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckChangedListener( ... );
        if (isCheckModeOn()) {
            ...
        } else {
           ...
        }
    }

    public boolean getCheckMode() { return checkMode; }
    public void setCheckMode(boolean checkMode) { this.checkMode = checkMode; }
}
```

Okay, now consider a situation where you need to extend both ExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter as well as CheckableAdapter, but you cannot extend two classes in Java. In other words you want all the functionalities of both classes to be brought into your class.

What's the correct way to resolve cases like this? Can anyone provide an example using the classes I've defined here?

Comment: Consider using composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: Can you provide an example using the class definitions I've written above?

Answer (score 2):

I think the "normal" answer would be to follow the well-known "prefer composition over inheritance". In the sense of: don't use inheritance to save a few lines of code, just put that extra bit of functionality into dedicated classes X and Z, and have those classes that need it create an object of X or Z, and call methods on those.

But the thing is: you are "stuffed" into the Android programming model. And I *think* that there is no easy solution for you in that context. Unless you find a way to

1. create a "generic" base class that extends Adapter
2. but that you can give *multiple* objects that could be used to "add" behavior to the Adapter methods

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean by "give multiple objects" to "add behavior"? Doesn't have to be actual working code, just pseudo-air-code to show what you mean.

Comment: Sorry, my answer is a "bit" unspecific for a reason - I am not too much into the Android model myself. I would have to dig into the javadoc for the classes you are using, to identify those parts that would need to go into a common interface. Then one has to figure how to reasonably implement those methods. Long story short: this is an interesting topic, but I think this is one of the questions that could be answered within 1 hour ... with 5 experienced folks in the same room having a discussion. In other words: something that can't be "really" answered with 50 or 100 lines of text

Comment: I can tell you that really the only shared components between the two would be the ViewHolder creation/binding methods.